# how to dynamically join tables in bigquery to avoid duplication of common columns

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, union, dynamicquery

I have 2 tables with a large number of columns (each has around 700-800 columns, which makes it not feasible to individually write all the column names). Both the tables have a few common rows. I need to dynamically union both the tables such that the common columns don't get repeated and are queried only once in the final table. For example:

```
TABLE 1:
+---------+--------+------+-------+
|firstname|lastname|upload|product|
+---------+--------+------+-------+
|    alice|       a|   100|apple  | 
|      bob|       b|    23|orange |
+---------+--------+------+-------+
```

TABLE 2:

```
+---------+--------+------+-------+
|firstname|lastname|books |active |
+---------+--------+------+-------+
|    alice|       a|   10 |yes    | 
|      bob|       b|    2 |no     |
+---------+--------+------+-------+
```

FINAL TABLE:

```
+---------+--------+------+-------+-----+------+
|firstname|lastname|upload|product|books|active|
+---------+--------+------+-------+-----+------+
|    alice|       a|   100|apple  | 10  | yes  |
|      bob|       b|    23|orange | 2   | no   | 
+---------+--------+------+-------+-----+------+
```

Comment: You should write a script to write your SQL. Extract the schema of every tables and only keep what's common between them.

Comment: please do not change/adjust already answered question! rather post new one!

Comment: Bigquery doesn't offer it, but read about SQL natural join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you a direction to look into

```
select *
from table1
join table2
using(firstname, lastname)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: What should I do if there are multiple common columns? Is there any way to do it without explicitly mentioning the common column names in the query?